# can't find the pattern of setting cascade logic

Tags: java, spring-boot, one-to-many, cascade, one-to-one

I have 3 tables which are Person Login and Account.

Person and Login is OneToOne relation and Login has one FK which is connected Person's id column called PERSON_ID.

Person(one) and Account(many) is OneToMany relation and Account has one FK which is connected Person's id column called PERSON_ID as well .

what i want to do is when i delete one data from Account , nothing happen to Person and Login.

if i delete one data from Person which id=1, Login's PERSON_ID=1 data will be deleted , and all of the data PERSON_ID=1 from Account will be deleted as well.

if i delete one data from Login which PERSON_ID=1, Person 's id=1 data will be deleted , and all of the data PERSON_ID=1 from Account will be deleted as well.

how should i set the cascade ?

i've tried dozens of times and still can't find the logic in there, thanks!!

here's my code of all 3 tables without setting cascade:

`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")

public class Person {
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name = "SEX")
private String sex;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Account> account;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "person")
private Login login;

@get..
@set..
}
```

`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
public class Account {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "ACCOUNT")
private String account;

@Column(name = "AMOUNT")
private String amount;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID")
public Person person;

@get..
@set..
}
```

`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOGIN")
public class Login {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
private long id;

@Column(name = "USERNAME")
private String userName;

@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
private String password;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private Person person;

@get..
@set..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but if I'm not mistaken you need to use the cascade=REMOVE option on the OneToMany and OneToOne relationships. In the OneToOne I think you need to specify cascade=REMOVE on the side that does NOT own the relationship, that is, the side that also contains the "mappedBy" property.

Finally, I believe JPA will NOT automatically load lazy relationships and then cascade them. I'm thinking you may need to fetch the relationship before you delete the parent entity (otherwise JPA will not know what to delete).

Comment: thanks for answering , but i've tried what you told me to do , now i can't delete Person's data directly , and if i delete Login's data , doesn't efffect Person and Account as well